# Problems calling ServiceStack services in-process with Validation & Filters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I need to be able to call my SS services from the controllers of an MVC application. Ideally i'd like to call them in-process to avoid the overhead of buiding a http request etc.

From scouring documentation I feel there are 2 suggested methods, but neither work fully.

1) ServiceGateway - Use the service gateway. This calls validation filters, but does not call other customer filters I've added. No option to applyFilters.

2) HostContext.ServiceController.Execute - There is a dedicated option on this method called applyFilters, and when I set it to true it works and applies filters and validation (though it only executes GlobalFilters, not TypedRequestFilters). However, if [CacheResponse] attribute is set on the service it overwrites and flushes a response to my client overriding the flow of the MVC controller and i don't know how to stop this. It does not do this if I set to applyFilters to false or if I take CacheResponse off. Changing the priority of the cache has no effect.

I'm calling the Execute method as follows from within an Action method on my controller:

```
HostContext.ServiceController.Execute(serviceRequest, HostContext.GetCurrentRequest(), true);
```

Before this method even returns control a response is flushed to the webpage on Chrome and then nothing/null is returned from method.

I feel there is regarding point 1) a feature missing and point 2) a bug in the implementation, though am not confident enough in my knowledge of SS to remedy either! Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Filters are executed as [part of the HTTP Request Pipeline](http://docs.servicestack.net/order-of-operations) and can terminate the current Request with a custom HTTP Response. You can check `IRequest.IsClosed` after executing the Request to check if it has been terminated by a Request Filter. They're behavior is incompatible with internal Gateway requests so there's no option to execute them in the Gateway.

I've marked these ServiceController methods as an In Process Request in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/dbb9e8f341910a0f946400436d4329fb9a846723) which should resolve the issue with the `[CacheResponse]` attribute which ignores In Process Requests.

This change is available from v4.5.13 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).